# Scheduling tasks in different times

Tags: android

Im doing some kind of Scheduler/Tasker of the bluetooth module, where you can specify multiple hours (HH:MM) when to turn ON/OFF. For what ive read, using Service to check if the time was reached, its battery expensive, so i discard that way.

Which its the better way to get this? Ive read some of AlarmManager, and also about ACTION_TIME_TICK (i think this requires the app to be running).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Alarm Manager to execute whatever code you wish to and it does not need your application to be running.

Comment: Do you know how to set execute multiple task at different time in different date?